# Time out when access localhost for ec2 ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, django

I am trying to access the local host for my ubuntu server hosted on ec2 when I run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I have my security setting set to

```
    port 80     0.0.0.0/0
```

and I want to access

```
http://ec2-somenumber.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000
```

currently it doesn't work in the command line, the app is currently running in port 8000

I ran

```
ubuntu@ip-somenumber:~/hello$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 25, 2014 - 23:41:00
Django version 1.6.3, using settings 'hello.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

and checked

```
netstat -nao | grep 80
```

returns

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::18280                :::*                                off (0.00/0/0)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6800     /run/udev/control
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6780
```

I also ran

```
ufw allow 8000
service ufw restart
```

but neither accessing the public dns or public ip

using the public ip

```
54.186.231.88:8000
```

or the public dns

```
ec2-54-186-231-88.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000
```

worked

What could be the problem?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Clarification on the down vote would be helpful in improving the quality of the question, does the question need more clarification, or is it too trivial and not appropriate?

Comment: do you have your security group allowing pot 8000 or 80? it seems you are mixing up the two in the question

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply, I set up port 22, 443 and 80 on the amazon security group dashboard, with both port 443 and 80 allowing `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: yes but you want to expose port 8000, so you need to add TCP 8000 to allow your origin IP address or 0.0.0.0/0 (everybody) in your security group, or start django debug server in port 80

Comment: Thanks, I am not exactly sure what you mean by exposing port 8000, do you mean handling ec2 VPC? I am currently using the default VPC, doesn't that allows you to access port 8000 remotely? If not, what are the necessary steps I need to do to expose port 8000?

Comment: I'm under the assumption that your ec2 instance is under a security group and that it has ports 22,443,80 enabled (allowing from 0.0.0.0). If that's the case you need to add port 8000 in the sec group (from web console) as well, otherwise the sec group is blocking requests to your django port. Or you can start django web server on port 80 since from your "grep" there's no service already there: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/SecurityGroup.html

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely the problem, I didn't realize that I have to add another port in the security group as I thought that I am accessing via http, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add port 8000 in the security group (from web console for example) as well, otherwise the security group is blocking requests to your django port. Or you can start django test web server on port 80 since from your "grep" there's no service already there.

For details on Security Groups: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/SecurityGroup.html